# Unpack a dictionary of dataframes and set key as column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dictionary (df) of dataframes:

```
([('Austria',
       Name                                     Value
 0     3 BG EMCore Convertibles Global CHF R T    5
 1     3 BG EMCore Convertibles Global R T        6
 [2 rows x 2 columns]),

('Belgium',
        Name                                    Value
 0      AG Life Alternative Investments           7
 1      AG Life Balanced                          1
 2      AG Life Bonds Global                      2
 3      AG Life Bonds Indexed                     7
 [4 rows x 2 columns])])
```

I want to convert the data into a single dataframe and simultaneously set as additional column the key strings

I first convert the dictionary into a list of dataframes:

`mylist=[i[1] for i in df.items()]`

Then I can merge the dataframes into a single dataframe by:

`master_frame=pd.concat(mylist, sort=True)`

But I want to set as additional column the keys from the dictionary

Expected result if like this:

```
       Name                                     Value     Country
 0     3 BG EMCore Convertibles Global CHF R T    5       Austria
 1     3 BG EMCore Convertibles Global R T        6       Austria
 2      AG Life Alternative Investments           7       Belgium
 3      AG Life Balanced                          1       Belgium
 4      AG Life Bonds Global                      2       Belgium
 5      AG Life Bonds Indexed                     7       Belgium
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, value in dictionary.items():
     df = value
     df.loc[:,'Country'] = key
     final_df = pd.concat([df, final_df], 0)
final_df
```

Comment: Works. I needed to add axis=0 in the concat part though and delete the 1.

Comment: @MartinYordanovGeorgiev Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4):

For a `dict` like:

```
dfs = {'Austria': AustriaDF, 'Belgium': BelgiumDF}
```

You can just add the new column based on the keys and then concat those:

```
for country, df in dfs.items():
    df['Country'] = country
master_frame = pd.concat(sorted(dfs.values(), key=lambda df: df['Country'][0]), ignore_index=True)
```

Value for `master_frame`:

```
                                      Name  Value  Country
0  3 BG EMCore Convertibles Global CHF R T      5  Austria
1      3 BG EMCore Convertibles Global R T      6  Austria
2          AG Life Alternative Investments      7  Belgium
3                         AG Life Balanced      1  Belgium
4                     AG Life Bonds Global      2  Belgium
5                    AG Life Bonds Indexed      7  Belgium
```

Comment: Works. Needed to replace dfs.iteritems with dfs.items though.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, will fix, old Python 2 habit.